# Arrowed SVG gradient with d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, gradient

Is there a way to use d3.js to create a gradient definition that will result in such:

Sorry for the previous ASCII, 
This is what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Instead of a simple linear gradient:

[image]

I didn't manage to find a way to do this without splitting the rects and creating opposing gradients.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example of what you're looking for? The ascii art is a little tricky to decipher..

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous ASCII, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Looking at [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html) it doesn't look like you can do something like that directly. Maybe if you combine a gradient and a pattern.

Comment: Patterns seem like an interesting way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With d3.js you are using SVG elements for drawing. SVG supports [linear](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradients) and [radial](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#RadialGradients) gradients. This arrow style gradient can be build from two different linear one.

The above links are describing the possible properties of gradients but it's not so trivial to use it from d3.js. So here is an [example for the radial gradient](http://freeconnection.blogspot.hu/2013/10/visual-story-about-zebra-d3js-animal.html) which is easy to translate into your version.

draw a rectangle with gradient:

```
var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "url(#gradient1)");
```

gradient has to be defined like in the above example:

```
var gradient1 = svgContainer.append("svg:defs")
    .append("svg:radialGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient1")
    .attr("cx", "50%")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved. Just posting an example of a bar chart with gradient and rounded corners. This will help you get any gradient effect.

```js
var data = [40, 50, 30, 40, 90, 54, 20, 40, 50, 30, 40, 90, 54, 20];
  var x = d3.scaleLinear() 
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) 
  .range([0, 420]);
  d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
  .attr("class","roundedCorners")
  .style("width", function(d) {
     return x(d) + "px";
   })
  .text(function(d) { 
     return d; 
  });
```

```css
.roundedCorners{
   border-radius: 0px 40px 40px 0px;
}
.chart div {
   background: rgb(254,204,177); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%, rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%, rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%, rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feccb1', endColorstr='#fb955e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   text-align: right;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 2px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart"></div>
```